Can I add a /29 network after the last /30 used in an ip range?
We currently break up 192.168.6.0 into multiple /30's.  Can I now add a /29 after the last used /30 subnet.  Example.  Last subnet is 192.168.6.24/30.  Can I now add 192.168.6.28/29.  Will this cause any routing issues?

A /29 can only start on multiples of 8 in the last octet. So your example doesn't work because 192.168.6.28 is not a network number for a /29 network; the "host" section of the address — the part not masked off by the subnet mask, so the 4's, 2's, and 1's-place bits in this case — must be zero. 192.168.6.24/29 or 192.168.6.32/29 would work as /29 subnets.
